# On what time lag is the FBI declassifying counterintelligence investigations?

Tags: united-states, fbi, justice-department, intelligence, counterintelligence

For a while now, the CIA has been declassifying as much old material as it can, on a lag of several decades, since the information in decades-old documents often no longer compromises sources and methods.  My question is, is the FBI undertaking similar declassification activity in regard to its past counterintelligence investigations?

If so, if the FBI is conducting a counterintelligence investigation now, how long would it be before we could expect that the results of that investigation to be declassified?

I ask because there have been several politically salient counterintelligence investigations in recent years whose existence has been reported on or disclosed, but which we haven’t gotten too much information about.

Comment: The same processes apply regardless of agency, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classified_information_in_the_United_States#Declassification